# How to get the 1st day of the current week if week starts from Monday in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)) AS FirstDayOfWeek
```

I am a beginner in Big query. This above query is giving me an error, please help me in correcting this.

Error message:

```
No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP_TRUNC for argument types: DATE, DATE_TIME_PART. Supported signature: TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP, DATE_TIME_PART, [STRING]) at [1:8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATE_TRUNC` instead of `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC`

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)) AS FirstDayOfWeek
```